# How to get instance of nested view model- knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The view has a heading followed by section with has submenus. the design for the viewmodels is below:

```
SettingsViewModel = function (pName) {
    var self = this;
    self.productName = ko.observable(pName), //heading
    self.sections = ko.observableArray([
            { checkboxID: ko.observable(), checkboxIDState: ko.observable(), sectionname: ko.observable(), sectionState: ko.observable() } 
        ]),  //submenus

    self.Addsections = function (checkboxid, sIdState, sName, sState) {
        this.sections.push({ checkboxID: checkboxid, checkboxIDState: sIdState, sectionname: sName, sectionState: sState });
    }
};


function MainViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.products = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.AddProducts= function (pname) {
        self.products.push(new SettingsViewModel(pname));
    }
};


$(document).ready(function () {
        VM = new MainViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(VM, document.getElementById("divd"));
    data= []; //some dummy data
    CallMEnus(data);

 });

 function CallMEnus(data) {
        var str = "";

        $(data).each(function (index, products) {
            VM.AddProducts(products.name);

                        $(products.section).each(function (index, section) {

                            var ChkboxId = "data";  
                            var chkboxIdState = 'datt';
                            var chkboxIdState += " checked";
                        }
            //how to call the products add section method?
                            VM.products()[index].Addsections(ChkboxId, chkboxIdState, section.name, section.state);  

                        });

        });
```

I need to call the AddSections method of the nested  SettingsViewModel from MainViewModel instance. How to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that parameter `index` from sections loop hides `index` from products loop. Just use another parameter name:

```
function CallMEnus(data) {
    var str = "";

    $(data).each(function (index, products) {
        VM.AddProducts(products.name);

        $(products.section).each(function(i, section) { // here
            var id = "data";
            var state = "checked";
            VM.products()[index].Addsections(id, state, section.name, section.state);
        });
    });
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lazyberezovsky/ZG3ET/2/)

Answer (score -1):

I would use a EventAggregator to decouple viewmodels, I've written this lightweight EventAggregator

http://jsfiddle.net/wJtun/4/

Subscribe:

```
MyApp.eventAggregator.subscribe(MyApp.DeleteCustomerMessage, this.customerDeleted, this);
```

Publish:

```
MyApp.eventAggregator.publish(new MyApp.DeleteCustomerMessage(this));
```

Comment: "I would use a EventAggregator to decouple viewmodels" is a perfect comment but not an answer. Please expand your answer to include how and why the OP should use an EventAggregator here and not just copy some sample code what you've written for something else.